# jQuery append eq() run through all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider of 6 images that I want to loop through seamlessly on mousemove like a carousel. On mousemove I am sliding them to the left until they go out of view. When the first one goes out of view, I append it to the end. But when the first one appends to the end, I can't get jQuery to update colors.eq(0) to the new first image. It keeps thinking colors.eq(0) is the one I already appended to the end. How can I tell jQuery to update eq(0) to be the new first element?

```
images.on('vmousemove', function(event) {    
    $(this).each(function() {
      var marginLeft = parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'), 10);
      $(this).css( "margin-left", "-=" +(speed % window.innerWidth / 6));
       if (marginLeft <= -30) {
          allImages.append(images.eq(0));
         }
      })
    })
```

Comment: Did you remove the first element after you appended it to the end?  If not, it still exists as element 0, even though it may not be visible.

Comment: Moving elements around within the DOM doesn't change element sequence within an existing jQuery object. (Why would it, bearing in mind that a jQuery object could hold multiple unrelated elements?) Instead of using 0 you could use an index variable to keep track of which is the currently left-most item. Also, why the .each() loop? Won't $(this) be a jQuery object with only one element?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Use **DOMSubtreeModified** event to update *colors* variable. And don't forget bind the **mousemove** event again on the updated *colors*.

```js
var colors = $('.color');

$('.container').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  colors = $('.color');
});

console.log('First element:' + colors.eq(0).attr('id'));

$('.container').append(colors.eq(0));

console.log('First element:' + colors.eq(0).attr('id'));
```

```css
.color {
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.color:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="color" id='1'>1</div>
  <div class="color" id='2'>2</div>
  <div class="color" id='3'>3</div>
  <div class="color" id='4'>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to *move* elements, not make copies.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.